# Get values of a binary variables

Tags: python, docplex

I have a MILP that I solved using docplex. Now I want to get the value of my binary variables ( binary_var_dict) after the resolution. Can anyone tell me how should I proceed ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the property `solution_value` of your variables to get this information.

Here's an example: https://github.com/IBMDecisionOptimization/docplex-examples/blob/master/examples/mp/modeling/nurses.py#L474

And here's the documentation: http://ibmdecisionoptimization.github.io/docplex-doc/mp/docplex.mp.linear.html?highlight=solution_value#docplex.mp.linear.Var.solution_value